# How to get the key value from a string when we use FlutterSecureStorage?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following String:

```
String readToken = await storage.read(key: 'token');
print(readToken);
```

The output will be:

```
flutter: "{\"accessToken\":\"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImFiNWUwYzcwMjYwNWU1MjRmMmZkOTQ2NTAwMDQyZDk1MzBlZWZhYjhkYjA0ZGZjYj<…>
```

The problem is that the readToken value is a String value so I become in a Map like this.

```
String decoded = jsonDecode(readToken);
```

And the output is:

```
flutter: {"accessToken":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImFiNWUwYzcwMjYwNWU1MjRmMmZkOTQ2NTAwMDQyZDk1MzBlZWZhYjhkYjA0ZGZjYjIwMWM1ZmE2NjJjOTQxNTA4OTg1MTZhZjBjNmIyYjRkIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiYWI1ZTBjNzAyNjA1ZTUyNGYyZmQ5<…>
```

So it looks like is a Map value but it isn't, because is still a String.

I would like to get just the value for access_token.

I tried

```
String dec = decoded.replaceAll(RegExp('"'), '');

int pos = dec.indexOf(':');

final token = dec.substring(pos + 1);
```

Comment: I'm expecting that the issue is related to how you store the `accessToken` in the secure storage. Can you provide this code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode your string to transform it to an actual Map.

For that you need to use `dart:convert` package and do the following: `json.decode(variable)`.

I would also suggest to store only the token value in FlutterSecureStorage and not the entire object.